# How to link feature and step definition in cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm new to Cucumber java and had this problem in initial stages:
I'm not using MAVEN project for some reason. I just created a simple java project in eclipse.

I have my features under "src/dummy/pkg/features", and my implementation "StepDef.java" is under "src/dummy/pkg/features/implementation"

I have written step definitions for Given, When, and Then, but when I run my features file, it is unable to recognize the implementation. How do I link the features with step definitions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create a class `YourClass` and it would look something like the below and run it as JUnit test.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(  monochrome = true,
                     features = "src/dummy/pkg/features/",
                       format = { "pretty","html: cucumber-html-reports",
                                  "json: cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" },
                         glue = "your_step_definition_location_package" )

public class YourClass {
  //Run this from Maven or as JUnit
}
```

Comment: that's correct we have to use glue = "pkg location" in the @CucumberOptions

Answer (score 4):

When you run your Runner class then it will scan all the feature file mentioned within **features** options and load the them afterward all step definition within package started by text mentioned within **glue** options will get loaded.
For e.g.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumberreports.json" }, 
        glue = "stepDefinition", 
        features = "src/test/resources/TestCases/", 
        tags={"@onlythis"},
        dryRun=false
    )
public class RunTest {

}
```

Here all the feature file present within

> src/test/resources/TestCases/

will get loaded

then all the stepdef within or it's subdirectory will get loaded

> stepDefinition

and whenever your step from feature get run then cucumber will look for function corresponding to step's regex and function will run.

for e.g.

whenever step **When User enters email id** in src/test/resources/TestCases/Login.feature will run then cucumber will find its corresponding function in all stepdef classes

```
Login.feature
@LoginValidation 
Feature: To smoke test functionalities of app 

@Browser @ValidLogin 
Scenario: Verify scenario in case of successful login 
    When User enters email id 
    And User enters password 
    Then User clicks on sign in button and able to sign in
```

And moment it will reach class in subdirectory of **stepDefinition** i.e. in 
 **stepDefinition.ui.home.LoginPageStepDef.java** cucumber will find function with **@When("^User enters email id$")** and will execute this function.

```
LoginPageStepDef.java
public class LoginPageStepDef {

    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(AttachHooks.driver);
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoginPageStepDef.class);

    @When("^User enters email id$")
    public void user_enters_email_id() throws Throwable {
        //LoginPage.obj = loginPage;
        loginPage.enterEmailId(ConfigManager.getProperty("UserName"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your project to Cucumber project. Right-click on your project from the Project Explorer > Configure > Convert as Cucumber Project.

Answer (score 1):

Create a runner class something like this and you should be able to execute.
There is also no need to write step definitions manually, just create a feature file and run it, it will create a snippet of the step definition which can be used to create a step definition class:

A class file called Runnerclass is required to run the cucumber:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty","html:format"},

features = "Features/name.feature",glue={"path where step definitions exist"})
public class RunnerClass {

}
```